# Can we animate ngFor so that the item will slide from left only if the item is visible on view port?

Tags: angular, animation, ngfor

i have an array with lots of items. And the ngFor will show only first items with a scroll. I have animated it so that each item will slide from left to the view port. But I want to have this animation to the bottom elements also which will be visible only if I scroll the div. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of :enter and :exit in *ngFor. Each element getting added to the array will have the animation dynamically.

Link: https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers

Just make sure, the dynamic elements are added to the control array once you have hit the bottom of the scroll.